# How to show/ hide components in react by clicking sibling component

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component "app.js" that contains child components such as header & chart.
The chart component has two child components (chart1 & chart2)
On header, I have 2 clickable links named (chart1, chart2) respectively. My goal is to show/hide each chart by clicking on the header links "chart1 & chart2".
As I understood, I need to create two states; isHiddenChart1 and isHiddenChart2 in the parent and pass them to header and chart components. Also, I need to create two functions; toggleHideChart1 & toggleHideChart2 that change the states each time I click on the links, and pass these functions to Header component.
However, I tried to do that but when clicking on the links in header nothing changes!

Following is app.js code

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isHiddenChart1: false,
      isHiddenChart2: true
    }
    this.toggleHiddenChart1 = this.toggleHiddenChart1.bind(this)
    this.toggleHiddenChart2 = this.toggleHiddenChart2.bind(this)
  }
  toggleHiddenChart1 () {
    this.setState({
      isHiddenChart1: !this.state.isHiddenChart1
    })
  }
  toggleHiddenChart2 () {
    this.setState({
      isHiddenChart2: !this.state.isHiddenChart2
    })
  }
render(){
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header 
              isHiddenChart1={this.state.isHiddenChart1}
              isHiddenChart2={this.state.isHiddenChart2}
              onClick={() => this.isHiddenChart1}
              onClick={() => this.isHiddenChart2}


      />
     <Chart 
            isHiddenChart1={this.state.isHiddenChart1}
            isHiddenChart2={this.state.isHiddenChart2}

     />
</React.Fragment>


  );
}
}
```

header.js

```
<Link to="#" onClick={()  => this.props.toggleHiddenChart1}> Chart1 </Link>
<Link to="#" onClick={()  => this.props.toggleHiddenChart2}> Chart2 </Link>
```

Chart.js

```
{!this.props.isHiddenChart1 && <Chart1 />}
{!this.props.isHiddenChart2 && <Chart2 />}
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to pass states and functions in react, but chart1 is displayed at the beginning and chart2 is hidden so passing states is working fine as I assume!

Comment: {!this.props.isHiddenChart1 && <Chart2 />} ... shouldn't this be `isHiddenChart2` instead?

Comment: Hey also you are passing 2 same handler that is onClick in Header Component

Comment: yes, that was a typo. Thank you for notifying

Answer (score 1):

I would rather not create 2 separate state variables I will only create a Single State variable which specifies which chart is Active.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeChart: null,
    };
    this.toggleChart = this.toggleChart.bind(this);
  }
  toggleChart(chart) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      activeChart:chart,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header
          activeChart={this.state.activeChart}
          onClick={this.toggleChart}
        />
        <Chart
          activeChart={this.state.activeChart}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

**Header.js**

```
<Link to="#" onClick={()  => this.props.toggleChart("chart1")}> Chart1 </Link>
<Link to="#" onClick={()  => this.props.toggleChart("chart2")}> Chart2 </Link>
```

**Chart.js**

```
switch(this.state.activeChart) {
 case "chart1":
   return <Chart1 />
 case "chart2":
   return <Chart2 />
 default: 
   return null;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As I see you need to do these changes:

header.js

```
<Link to="#" onClick={()  => this.props.toggleHiddenChart1()}> Chart1 </Link>
<Link to="#" onClick={()  => this.props.toggleHiddenChart2()}> Chart2 </Link>
```

Chart.js

```
{!this.props.isHiddenChart1 && <Chart1 />}
{!this.props.isHiddenChart2 && <Chart2 />}
```

and pass appropriate props to the Header component instead of `onClick`

```
toggleHiddenChart1={() => this.isHiddenChart1}
toggleHiddenChart2={() => this.isHiddenChart2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a single state to store which chart is being shown because

- it is more scalable, you can easily extend to more chart options
- since the two charts are mutual exclusive i.e only one can show at any time, you are essentially duplicating information, which isn't good practice. If chart1 is hidden automatically means chart2 is showing.
- it's less code!

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { chartId: 1 }

    this.toggleChart = this.toggleChart.bind(this)
  }

  toggleChart (chartId) {
    this.setState({
      chartId: chartId
    })
  }

  render(){
   return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Link to="#" onClick={_ => toggleChart(1)}> Chart1 </Link>
      <Link to="#" onClick={_ => toggleChart(2)}> Chart2 </Link>
      <Chart chartId={this.state.chartId} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
  }
}
```

```
export default ({ chartId }) => {
   switch(chartId) {
      case 1:
        return <Chart1 />
      case 2:
        return <Chart2 />
      default:
        throw new Error('invalid chart id')  

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping, I realized that I have to pass the function back up to the parent. Also as you suggested I used only one state to determine what could be displayed/hidden

app.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isHidden: false,
    }
    this.toggleHidden = this.toggleHidden.bind(this)
  }
  toggleHidden () {
    this.setState({
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    })
  }

render(){
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header 
              isHidden={this.state.isHidden}
              clickMe={this.toggleHidden}    
      />         
     <Chart 
            isHidden={this.state.isHidden}    
     />
    </React.Fragment>


  );
}
}
```

header.js

```
    toggled = (ev) =>{
    this.props.clickMe()
    }


        render() {
            return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Link to="#" onClick={this.toggled}>
             <Chart1/>
            </link>
            <Link to="#" onClick={this.toggled}>
             <Chart2/>
            </link>
          </React.Fragment>
              )
          }
```

charts.js

```
{!this.props.isHidden && <Chart1 />}
{this.props.isHidden && <Chart2 />}
```